# Integrating `pqR` and `R` with `littler`

Tags: r, bash

In Ubuntu my `base-r` lives in `/usr/bin/R`. When I built `pqR` from source it installed to `/usr/local/bin/R`. Bash looks in `/usr/local/bin` first so by default now `R` calls `pqR 2.15`, not core `R 3.0`.

I was able to redefine these in `~/.bashrc` with `alias`. But, a few surprises remain. `man R` still refers to `pqR`, as does `littler` run by default with `pqR`.

I'd prefer to set things back to the way they were, and only call `pqR` when I specifically want to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need manage to set up `PATH` and `MANPATH`, if you need `/usr/bin` in the first, just put it before `/usr/local/bin`.

```
PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
MANPATH=/usr/share/man:$MANPATH     #this setting for Solaris, maybe it is different path
export PATH MANPATH
```

put in `~/.bashrc`